# Economic Reviews/Journals for High School students

Tags: research-process, paper-submission, review-articles, economics

I am a 10th grader and I am looking for a journal/review to publish my paper in the subject of macroeconomics. Is anyone aware of any journal/review that would allow me as a highschooler to publish such a piece?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Unfortunately, your question is likely to be closed, as we do not recommend journals. Still, [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18184/is-it-possible-for-a-high-school-student-with-no-academic-qualifications-to-publ) question may be worth reviewing.

Comment: Also -- you should try the economics forum here on SE.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. And any journal, in theory, will accept your work. However, I think you should seek out some feedback from an economist in the related area. Also, it is an unfortunate reality that econ journals are very 'clubby'.

As an aside -- i am a PhD student studying macroeconimics. If you want to try and provide some idea of what you're doing, I can try to give you advice about journals etc. And feel free to be however vauge you think you need to be to protect your idea.